# Open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to save to an internal storage (not external). This is the code I have in Kotlin

```
private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        var outStream: FileOutputStream? = null
        try {
            val dir = File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "ALCS"+ File.separator + "LaneShots")
            val fileName = String.format("%s_%d.jpg", "Image", System.currentTimeMillis())
            if(!dir.exists()){
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            val outFile = File(dir, fileName)
            outStream = FileOutputStream(outFile) ==> ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream)
            outStream!!.flush()
            outStream!!.close()
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

I get the error `Documents/ALCS/LaneShots/Image_1601958600007.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

This is in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have tried using this code:

```
val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "ALCS"+ File.separator + "LaneShots")
```

to no avail.

Comment: The code is correct. I just needed to make the permission run on runtime.

Comment: That path is not correct. It does not exist. It is impossible. The last mentioned path in external public is ok. But if device runs Android 10 you should have said so.

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();` That failed already. But you dont know as you did not check the return value. And so not acted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(contentResolver, bitmap, "YOUR IMAGE NAME", "Image Saved")`

Other than this I would recommend, if you are using the output method, change the directory to Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES